# iOS8 - push notification permission popup appears directly without a method

Tags: ios, ios8, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning

I would like to have a response from someone else and confirm if this is something that has changed on iOS8 or if I have another problem in my project.
I was trying to move the notification permission popup and call it later, but after several test I see I cannot do that with iOS8, it works fine on iOS7.

And I have the following confirmations:

-On iOS8 there's no need to call "registerForRemoteNotifications", the popup appears anyway. (it was "registerForRemoteNotificationsTypes" before but now is deprecated on iOS8 and there seems to be a "registerForRemoteNotifications" that is referenced on the official documentation but there's no documentation for that new method specifically)
(https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html)

-I removed the entitlements from my app and the popup also appears, so probably it takes that info from the prov instead of descriptor.

Any though on this? anyone can confirm if this is true?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not so much documentation about this, but after watching an official video from Apple, and reading more about all these new functionalities for notifications on iOS8, I could understand what's happening with the popup.

- First I was using AIR 14 that had a bug for iOS8 and the permission popup appeared even without calling any specific native method in UIApplication, that was fixed on AIR 15.0
- Also, there's no more permission popup for remote notification on iOS8, users can receive notifications by default, and they can disable that from the device settings (anyway we should request the token as usual).
- The permission popup that we see in iOS8 is for local notifications, and it appears when we call this method:

  ```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  ```

All that explains the weird behavior that I had before, and actually I could clarify and fix this issue.